# Can a bash heredoc put its result directly into a variable?

Tags: bash

I have some code like this:

```
CMD=$(cat <<EOC
docker run 
   -p $MY_IP:$LOCAL_PORT:$LOCAL_PORT -p $MY_IP:$PEER_PORT:$PEER_PORT 
   -v $CERT_DIR:/cert 
   $ETCD_IMAGE 
   --name $MACHINE.$DOMAIN 
   --peer-cert-file=/cert/server-cert.pem
   --peer-key-file=/cert/server-key.pem --peer-ca-file=/cert/ca.pem 
   --peer-addr=$MY_IP:$PEER_PORT 
   --peers=$OIPPC
EOC
)
```

is there a way to get a here doc to assign result directly to variable in bash without intervening process (cat)?  This code works, it just feels like too much work.

Comment: Why are you using a heredoc here at all? If you just want that string in the `CMD` variable (you don't by the way, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for why) then just use a quoted string directly `CMD="docker run ...."`.

Comment: thanks for the pointer.  i am using the heredoc because i want to echo the command (if verbose is requested by invoker), log the command, and finally run it.  i am used to heredocs from python/perl and comfortable with them.  i am seeing they are the wrong thing to use.

Comment: What does a heredoc have to do with echoing the command? The assignment to the variable lets you do that regardless. Also, `set -x` is likely a much better `verbose` mode then manually echoing commands (though very much *more* verbose and a bit odder to read on occasion).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> How to put a here-string into a variable in Bash:

In Bash use `read` with the `-d` delimiter set to null:

```
IFS= read -r -d '' cmd <<EOC
    ...blah blah...
EOC
```

Make sure you really use `IFS=` like shown, in front of `read`, otherwise any leading and trailing spaces will be trimmed. Make sure you use `-r` otherwise some backslashes would be understood as escape backslashes.

Some would argue that it's simpler to just use a plain assignment as:

```
cmd='
    ...blah blah...
'
```

But sometimes you have lots of quotes to the point that it becomes simpler and nicer to use this.

**Subtle note.** With this, `read` returns a failure return code (1) since the null-byte delimiter is not read before EOF. While this is alright most of the times, it can be a problem if you're using `set -e` (but [you really shouldn't use `set -e` anyway](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)). If you want to be sure, add:

```
IFS= read -r -d '' cmd <<EOC || true
    ...blah blah...
EOC
```

---

### Now, seriously, about your problem.

Below is a *serious note that you really should take into account*: don't put code into strings! [it's broken!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Instead, use a function or (still bad, but not broken) an array. Here's how you would use an array:

```
mycommand=(
    docker run 
        -p "$MY_IP:$LOCAL_PORT:$LOCAL_PORT"
        -p "$MY_IP:$PEER_PORT:$PEER_PORT"
        -v "$CERT_DIR":/cert
        "$ETCD_IMAGE"
        --name "$MACHINE.$DOMAIN"
        --peer-cert-file=/cert/server-cert.pem
        --peer-key-file=/cert/server-key.pem
        --peer-ca-file=/cert/ca.pem 
        --peer-addr="$MY_IP:$PEER_PORT"
        --peers="$OIPPC"
)
```

(observe the quotes that I took time to type, with love).
Then you can safely run it (by safely I mean it's all right if you're having glob characters or quotes or spaces in your arguments) as:

```
"${mycommand[@]}"
```

(observe the healthy quotes, again). If you want to print the command, use this:

```
printf '%s\n' "${mycommand[*]}"
```

Unfortunately, the line breaks won't be preserved here. But really, that shouldn't be a problem at all. If really needed, you should pass this command through a formatter of some sort (well, very likely it doesn't exist so you'll have to code it yourself). But put the things in the right order: you want to define a *command*, to execute it (and, optionally format it, for user display), not the other way round, have a string that's nice to the user's eyes that you then have to parse (dangerously) to transform into code.

Comment: > ...with love... | Please stay safe, dear @gniourf_gniourf...