# Expand selected variables within here-document while invoking Bash through SSH

Tags: mysql, bash, ssh, heredoc

I don't have remote access to a MySQL server, so I am trying to do it via an SSH session.

It partly works, but not correctly.

```
sshpass -p $password ssh user@$IP /bin/bash << EOF
mysql -N -uroot -ppassword test -e "select id from client where user ='$user'"
EOF
```

This will show the result of the select statement, but I'd like to be able to use that result in another echo statement.

eg:

```
The user ID is: xxxxx
```

I tried to assign the output to a variable using:

```
sshpass -p $password ssh user@$IP /bin/bash << EOF
res=$(mysql -N -uroot -ppassword test -e "select id from client where user ='$user'")
echo $res
EOF
```

But that results in:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

If I quote EOF like `'EOF'` then I can get the result into `res` but I lose the ability to use `$user`

Is there anyway to do this so I can use my variable in the heredoc and get the result of the MySQL query to a new variable ?

Comment: This might help: [How to assign a heredoc value to a variable in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1167746/3776858) or [Can a bash heredoc put its result directly into a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28565623/3776858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I quote EOF like `'EOF'` then I can get the result in to `res` but I lose the ability to use `$user`

You can pass `$user` to bash as a positional parameter and still have the quoted EOF and its advantages. E.g:

```
sshpass -p "$password" ssh "user@$IP" /bin/bash -s "$user" << 'EOF'
res=$(mysql -N -uroot -ppassword test -e "select id from client where user ='$1'")
echo $res
EOF
```

Bash manual describes the `-s` option as follows.

> **If the -s option is present**, or if no arguments remain after option processing, **then commands are read from the standard input.  This option allows the positional parameters to be set when invoking an interactive shell or when reading input through a pipe.**