# How can i store the below sql connect and query in a variable within a shell script

Tags: sql, linux, bash, shell, sh

I am trying to store the SQL query below in a variable within a shell script.

```
sqlplus -s 'username/password@"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname.com)(PORT=portnumber)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=Servicename)))"' <<EOF
SPOOL /tmp/out.txt
select count(scheduletaskid)from devicetask where status=6 group by coreid;
SPOOL OFF
exit;
EOF
```

Comment: Or this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565623/can-a-bash-heredoc-put-its-result-directly-into-a-variable

Comment: what have you tried and what was your problem buddy?

Comment: **Don't use `eval`!** The accepted answer on the duplicate suggests this, but don't trust it just because it is accepted.